# How to compute $\int^{1}_{-1}f(x)dx$?

Tags: integration, functions, definite-integrals

I need to compute
$\displaystyle\int^{1}_{-1}\,{\rm f}\left(\, x\,\right)\,{\rm d}x$, where
$$
\,{\rm f}\left(\, x\,\right)
=\left\{\begin{array}{lcrcl}
x & \mbox{if} & x & \leq & 0
\\[2mm]
x^{2} & \mbox{if} & x & \geq & 0
\end{array}\right.
$$

I know that $\displaystyle\int^{1}_{-1}x\,{\rm d}x=0$ and
$\displaystyle\int^{1}_{-1}x^{2}\,{\rm d}x = {2 \over 3}$.

Is it right ?.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\int_{-1}^1f(x)dx=\int_{-1}^0f(x)dx+\int_0^1f(x)dx$$

By the ranges of definition, this

$$=\int_{-1}^0x\ dx+\int_0^1 x^2\ dx$$

Comment: The result: $$-\dfrac{1}{6}$$

Comment: Hello,@lab bhattacharjee ,I konw you $113k$ how get it .HaHa

Comment: @math110, Not sure if I understood your point clearly.